# How to load csv data into salesforce ?

Tags: csv, salesforce, loading

I have been trying to load the csv file into Salesforce. I have tried through excel ad-ins but unable to do.
Please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Data Import Wizard under Setup or the Data Loader tool to load CSV:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=import_with_data_import_wizard.htm&type=5

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader